# Deleting from minicart items causing issue

Tags: magento2, mini-cart, delete

I am trying to delete from top minicart 
and getting this strange error:

> Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to 
>       Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException::__construct() must be an instance
>       of Magento\Framework\Phrase, string given, 
>       called in /home/pocketgrocery/public_html/vendor/magento/module-
>       quote/Model/ShippingAddressManagement.php 
>       on line 121 and defined in /home/pocketgrocery/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Exception/InputException.php
>   on line 51

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

I show many similar kind of  error posts & questions

`Recoverable Error: Argument {digit(s)} passed to...`

As per my knowledge this error come because of we injected some class(es) in a constructor of a class,

that respective class already available in `generation` folder. so need to clean respective file from `generation` folder or clear `generation` folder data (except `.htaccess` file).

See changes in store front error will solved.